How to add matplotlibcpp.h library to VS-Code
I'm on Windows and I'm trying to include the "matplotlibcpp" library into my C++ project in VS-Code. I already have Python and Matplotlib installed.
This would be a minimal example:
#include <iostream>
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;
int main() {
    plt::plot({1,3,2,4});
    plt::show();
}

However I get following two errors:
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit

cannot open source file "matplotlibcpp.h"C/C++(1696)

The file can be taken from the Github repository, but when I add it to my project folder there are additional files missing and I'm also unsure on how to add the path.
I couldn't find any good resources on this, so help would be much appreciated!

Update: I looked at the configuration files and I added the path of the project directory to my "settings.json" file:
{
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++17",
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include",
        "C:\\Users\\xxxx" // I added the directory of my project here
    ],
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [

        ]
    }
}

This made the first error go away however I now get the following:
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:matplotlibcpp_test: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:matplotlibcpp_test:3: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status


Edit, Additional files:
"tasks.json"
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "msbuild",
            "args": [
                // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/t:build",
                // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary",
                "-lgdplus",
                "-igdi32"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}

"c_cpp_properties.json" (I had to manually add this to my folder like here but the error remains the same)
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
            "compilerPath": "cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}


VSCode is very configurable with many different ways to set it up, but most of the time a problem like this stems from improperly configuring tasks.json or (this is a mathematical or, so both could be wrong) c_cpp_properties.json. If VSCode is using these two files, please add them to the question. If VSCode is using some other system, you'll need to specify which method and add the configuration files for that method. Without the configuration we can do very little for you.

What other files should I add?

Variations on this line, "C:\\Users\\xxxx" // I added the directory of my project here, in settings.json should be in tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json. Post those two files and someone here can show you where and what the modification should look like. I've use VS Code just enough to know I dislike the tool, and don't have the experience to make recommendations beyond avoiding its use.

There's a lot of confusion here. Forget VSC for now, compile it directly in the terminal. Then figure out how to run the same commands from VSC, because that's all it does. Second, choose a compiler. Are you using MinGW or MSVC? I'm seeing a mix of both in the configs.

I'm using MinGW. I ran a hello world script in the cmd and it worked fine. When I then tried to do the same with the minimal file "matplotlibcpp_test.cpp", I got following error: "cc1plus.exe: fatal error: matplotlibcpp_test.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated."

Please add @username when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications. "matplotlibcpp_test.cpp: No such file or directory" - This should be easy to debug. It means there's no such file, or it's not in the current directory (either cd to it or specify absolute or relative path).

@HolyBlackCat That's right but I'm having trouble correctly adding it. I already found the Github repository for "matplotlibcpp.h" (see original question), but when I download and add it into the same directory as my "matplotlibcpp_test.cpp" file I get another error: matplotlibcpp.h:5:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
5 | #include <Python.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

The library requires Python to be installed. Install it in msys2 using pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python3.

@HolyBlackCat I did that and restarted everything, but the error didn't go away. I think I need an actuall "python.h" file in my directory right?

No you don't need to copy the installed python.h anywhere. Run pkgconf --libs --cflags python3 and add the compiler flags it prints to your compilation command (might need to install pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkgconf first).

@HolyBlackCat I ran your commands in MSYS MINGW64 and I also had to install numpy, cmake and ninja. After that i ran following command in the cmd: g++ matplotlibcpp_test.cpp -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/python3.11 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/_core/include -lpython3.11 -o matplotlibcpp_test.exe And I then got the error:

matplotlibcpp.h: At global scope:
matplotlibcpp.h:354:20: error: redefinition of 'struct matplotlibcpp::detail::select_npy_type'
354 | template <> struct select_npy_type { const static NPY_TYPES type = NPY_INT64; };
|                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
matplotlibcpp.h:345:20: note: previous definition of 'struct matplotlibcpp::detail::select_npy_type'
345 | template <> struct select_npy_type<int64_t> { const static NPY_TYPES type = NPY_INT64; };
|                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

matplotlibcpp.h:356:20: error: redefinition of 'struct matplotlibcpp::detail::select_npy_type'
356 | template <> struct select_npy_type { const static NPY_TYPES type = NPY_UINT64; };
|                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
matplotlibcpp.h:349:20: note: previous definition of 'struct matplotlibcpp::detail::select_npy_type'
349 | template <> struct select_npy_type<uint64_t> { const static NPY_TYPES type = NPY_UINT64; };
|                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The library is bugged (or not written in a cross-platform manner, rather). In select_npy_type, they shouldn't have used any of the [u]intN_t types, only the standard [unsigned] {char|short|long|long long}.

@HolyBlackCat Is there a solution to this or a different matplotlibcpp.h file? I've seen other people run Matplotlib in c++ (for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xp3ntYGs8No). So there has to be a way to make it work.

They are likely using the lib on a different OS and/or compiler. I'd just fix the header manually, as I described in the previous comment.

@HolyBlackCat I ran the same command from above and it atleast compiles. But when I run the exe there are still packages missing/problems with numpy: (Btw thanks for helping me so much)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
